# How do I set up my ASP.NET Development Server correctly?

Tags: c#, javascript, mysql, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcj9G.png

Above is what happens when I try to run my website I have set up in Visual Studio 2010 for Web Development (ASP.NET). The website should be able to run (there is a live version of the website working, this is just a local copy). Maybe I did something wrong while setting it up?

Comment: I don't think that development server runs in www.xxxx.com.

Comment: looks like you are missing a colon in your url: it should be http:// not http//

Comment: Have you published your asp.net web application in IIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you miss - based on your linked image -  is a colon after '`http`' (and before '`//`'), so change the address to

```
http://localhost:56059...
```

Or you can simply remove the '`http://`' part and use '`localhost:56059...`' instead.

Hope this helps.